# $f$ is a continuous function on $[0,1]$, show that there exists $c \in (0,1)$ such that $\int_{0}^{1}xf(x){\rm d}x = \int_{c}^{1}f(x){\rm d}x$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

If $f$ is a continuous real valued function on $[0,1]$, show that there exists a point $c \in (0,1)$ such that $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}xf(x){\rm d}x = \int_{c}^{1}f(x){\rm d}x$

I am sensing Rolle's theorem here. But I do not know how do I do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**: Let $g(c) = \displaystyle\int_{c}^{1}f(x)\,dx$. Then, the average value of $g(c)$ over $c \in [0,1]$ is:

$g_{\text{avg}} = \displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}g(c)\,dc = \int_{0}^{1}\int_{c}^{1}f(x)\,dx\,dc = \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{x}f(x)\,dc\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}xf(x)\,dx$.

Answer (score 2):

I have too many methods for the problem.
first: Bonnet formula,obviouly,too easy,as long as you know the formula.
second:weierstrass formula,obviously,too easy,as long as you know the formula.

third: define $F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(t){\rm d}t$
$\int_{0}^{1}xf(x){\rm d}x=\int_{0}^{1}x{\rm d}F(x)=F(1)-\int_{0}^{1}F(x){\rm d}x=F(1)-F(c)=\int_{c}^{1}f(x){\rm d}x$

Comment: You're very close to making the math formulas.  If you want to write math, just write it between dollar signs.  So to write the equation $x + 3$, I would write $\text{ \$ x + 3 \$}$.  Also, for the integral symbol, you would write \int.  So $\int f(x) \,dx$ is written as $\text{ \$ \int f(x) dx \$}$.

Comment: Finally, if you want to put limits of integration, like $\int_{0}^{c}$, you would type $\text{\$ \int_{0}^{c} \$}$.

Comment: @user46944 thank you very much,I have never learnt any skill about that,I think I need to learn it now

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you mind explaining the first and second methods? Also, I can't quite make out the equations in your third method. Specifically, what are the bounds on each of the integrals?

Comment: @JimmyK4542  you may refer to the second mean value theorem for integrals,two types:Weierstrass,Bonnet